# Gray dots in itemize

Tags: color, lists, itemize

Using `itemize`, how can I use a gray big dot as `\item` instead of the black one by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro `\labelitemi` contains the symbol for the first level of `itemize`, it can be redefined to:

```
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{gray}{\textbullet}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{gray}{\textbullet}}

\begin{document}
\blinditemize
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]